# openssl speed: any way to test only one curve in ECDSA?

Tags: openssl

I have been testing ECDSA speed with

```bsh
openssl speed ecdsa
```

It took more than 7 minutes to report 22 curves. However, in most cases I only care about NIST P-256 (obviously), so it’s a waste of time for me to run so many niche curves. Is there something like

```bsh
openssl speed ecdsa/nistp256
```

in OpenSSL? I checked [the manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-speed.html) but didn’t find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this works:

```
openssl speed ecdsap256
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed this hint and found [all the ECDSA algorithm-IDs for speed test](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/eb27a90e41a62d3337c5e21e24ee72f1e49a445c/apps/speed.c#L380-L406). The same source file has IDs for other algorithm as well. I’m sad that this isn’t properly documented.

Comment: @FranklinYu Your link is even more useful for those who try to avoid NIST curves, thanks! I think you should make your comment an answer for everyone to see, and accept yours.